# IGV crashing on Mac

Tags: java, macos

I tried to open IGV v2.7 on my mac (OS X 10.10.5) from app and command line. It chashed every time. 
Here the reported error. I don't know how to solve it. 
Thank you in advance for the help.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff8bfebf72, pid=1408, tid=1811
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.2+9) (build 11.0.2+9)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.2+9, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_c.dylib+0xf72]  strlen+0x12
```